# What data type column to use with short_uuid

Tags: mysql, sql

I've decided to use [uuid_short](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short) mysql function to generate ids for my primay key. My questions is what type of data type for the column I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section you linked states that uuid_short returns a "a 64-bit unsigned integer". That would suggest [BIGINT UNSIGNED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) is the type to use for your keyed column.

Comment: On other websites people mentioned binary so I I am confused

Comment: @IdanShechter Some people go mad with this and try to compress the UUID so it takes up less space in the db. If the number of bytes doesn't map to built in type's size then binary is an option.

Comment: So you guys sure that bigint is the 'normal' way to go as stated in the MySQL documentation? - Just want to be sure :] - see this: http://pastebin.com/CSkTG30c